# disabled tls1 in apache-tomcat but can still connect with openssl s_client, why?

Tags: tomcat, openssl, tls1.2

so i have disabled tls v1 in my tomcat config:

using the following jsse connector:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
    <SSLHostConfig protocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2">     
    <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="/root/.keystore" certificateKeystorePassword="changeit" 
                     type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

but when i test to check if my tlsv1 connections get refused iam still able to connect with below, can someone explain why the client is still able to connect [CONNECTED(00000003)] ?

---

```
# openssl s_client -connect ip:8080 -tls1
CONNECTED(00000003)
140199874680720:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:s3_pkt.c:365:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1600203654
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

any feedback would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: SSL/TLS works by first making a TCP connection and then doing a 'handshake' to establish security _over_ that TCP connection, followed if successful by secured data exchange and ending with closure. You are getting the TCP connection and than a failure of the TLS handshake on that connection, exactly as you should.

Comment: thanks for the explanation Dave! i guess i just rushed to conclusion and misread the sclient output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a failed s_client connection:

```
140199874680720:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:s3_pkt.c:365:
```